# SML: Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

Tags: sml

I'm trying to write a SML function that has two argument, the first is an 
int and the second is a list of lists. The objective is to insert the first argument onto the front of every list in the second arguemnt. For example, `append_to_front(1,[[3,4],[6,8],[]])` should return `[[1,3,4],[1,6,8],[1]]`.

I have the code:

```
fun append_to_front(a:int, L:int list list) =
    if L = []
    then []
    else a::hd(L)::append_to_front(a, tl(L));
```

and I get the error message: *Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]*. Why?

Comment: You can also solve this with a higher-order function: `fun append_to_front (x, L) = map (fn xs => x::xs) L`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cons operator `::` has type `'a * 'a list -> 'a list`, that is, it requires an element on the left and a list on the right. Moreover, it is right-associative, i.e., `a::b::c = a::(b::c)`.

In your case, `a` has type `int`, `b` and `c` both have type `int list`. Consequently, the second use of `::` isn't well-typed, because it has a list on both sides. Use list concatenation `@` in that place instead.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I solved my problem by adding parentheses to (a::hd(L)).